# Selecting Columns from different tables using where in

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to retrieve data from columns of different tables using  Where-In clause but unable to do so. The required task is: "List name, package Weight and units Produced  and Batch no of all the products that are expired"

The database looks like this

```
create table Products(
    ProductId int,
    ProductName varchar(20) not null,
    PackageWeight float not null,
    PricePerUnit int not null,
    AmountInStore int,
    Primary Key(ProductId)
)

insert into Products values(1, 'Chicken Cutlet', 0.5, 500, 600)
insert into Products values(2, 'Chicken Cutlet', 0.25, 250, 0)
insert into Products values(3, 'Chicken Cutlet', 1, 1000, 500)
insert into Products values(4, 'Chicken Cutlet', 5, 4500, 600)
insert into Products values(5, 'Chicken Tenders', 300, 500, 500)
insert into Products values(6, 'Chicken Tenders', 600, 500, 100)
insert into Products values(7, 'Potato Fries', 1, 150, 0)
insert into Products values(8, 'Potato Fries', 5, 750, 800)

create table Production(
    ProductId int,
    BatchNo char(6) ,
    UnitsProduced int not null,
    DateOfProduction date not null,
    ExpiryDate date not null,
    Foreign Key(ProductId) references Products(ProductId),
    Primary Key(ProductId, BatchNo)
)

insert into Production values(1, '1-1001', 1000, '2014-01-01', '2014-01-10')
insert into Production values(2, '1-1001', 1000, '2014-01-01', '2014-01-10')
insert into Production values(3, '1-1001', 1000, '2014-02-01', '2014-02-10')
insert into Production values(4, '1-2001', 500, '2014-05-01', '2014-10-30')
insert into Production values(5, '1-2001', 500, '2014-05-10', '2030-11-10')
```

So far I have this:

```
select ProductName, PackageWeight from Products where ProductId in(
select ProductId from Products
Intersect
select ProductId from Production where ExpiryDate < GETDATE())
```

I am getting the correct Product name and package weight because they are both from the same table i.e Products, but how can I also retrieve `BatchNo`, `UnitsProduced` from a different table i.e Production in the same query?

Comment: Expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT P.ProductName, P.PackageWeight, PD.BatchNo, PD.UnitsProduced
FROM Products P
JOIN Production PD ON P.ProductId = PD.ProductId
WHERE ExpiryDate < CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `join` the tables based on `ProductId`, try like following query.

If you want to modify your existing query it should be like.

```
SELECT productname, 
       packageweight, 
       prdn.batchno, 
       prdn.unitsproduced 
FROM   products prd 
       INNER JOIN production prdn 
               ON prd.productid = prdn.productid 
WHERE  prd.productid IN(SELECT productid 
                        FROM   products 
                        INTERSECT 
                        SELECT productid 
                        FROM   production 
                        WHERE  expirydate < Getdate())
```

But if you want, you can re-factor your query like following.

```
SELECT productname, 
       packageweight, 
       prdn.batchno, 
       prdn.unitsproduced 
FROM   products prd 
       INNER JOIN production prdn 
               ON prd.productid = prdn.productid 
WHERE  expirydate < Getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by using `sql server views`. 
Here is how you can do it:

**Create a view**

```
-- Note that Table Alias is Used For Query Clarity
-- 'P' => For Product Table
-- 'Pr' => For Production Table
CREATE VIEW viewName
AS
SELECT P.ProductId AS ID,
       P.ProductName AS Name,
       P.PackageWeight,
       P.PricePerUnit,
       P.AmountInStore,
       Pr.BatchNo,
       Pr.ExpiryDate,
       Pr.UnitsProduced,
       Pr.DateOfProduction
FROM Production AS Pr
INNER JOIN
Products AS P
ON Pr.ProductId = P.ProductId;
```

**Get The Results as follows**

```
SELECT Name,
   PackageWeight,
   BatchNo,
   UnitsProduced
FROM viewName
WHERE ExpiryDate < GETDATE();
```

[image: you will have the output like this]